# Component.InvokeAsync in foreach loop doesn't work

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor

I have problem with display Component in Foreach loop:

**I. First case - component work:**

I create simple component (named HelloComponent) like that:

```
<h3>Hello Adam!</h3>
```

When i run it using:

```
///My code before component

await Component.InvokeAsync("HelloComponent");

///My code after component
```

Everythink work, and i got:

```
///My code before component

Hello Adam!

///My code after component
```

**II. Second case - component doesn't work:**

In View where i run component my code looks like:

```
@{
    List<string> options = new List<string>();
    options.Add("Adam");
    options.Add("Adrian");
    options.Add("Bart");   
}

///My code before component

@foreach(var item in options)
{
    <h3>Test header</h3>
    await Component.InvokeAsync("HouseOptionsComponent");
}

///My code after component
```

I got:

```
///My code before component

Test header
Test header
Test header

///My code after component
```

The foreach loop runs three times but does not get the component content. I believe I should have received:

```
///My code before component

Test header
Hello Adam!
Test header
Hello Adam!
Test header
Hello Adam!

///My code after component
```

Comment: What is "HouseOptionsComponent"?

Comment: Hi @AdamWróbel, May I know whether the reply has solved the problem or is there any update about this thread? If you have any question about my reply, please let me know freely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> `Component.InvokeAsync("HelloComponent");`
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> `Component.InvokeAsync("HouseOptionsComponent");`
> ```

Please check the Name of view component, you are invoking different View. Try to change the view name from `HouseOptionsComponent` to `HelloComponent`.